# Using r googledrive package to create custom property

Tags: r

According to the documentation for drive_mkdir() in the googledrive package, "Named parameters to pass along to the Drive API. Has the tidy dots semantics that come from using rlang::list2(). You can affect the metadata of the target file by specifying properties of the Files resource via .... Read the "Request body" section of the Drive API docs for the associated endpoint to learn about relevant parameters." In the Google Drive API, it lists adding custom properties as, "Custom file properties are key/value pairs used to store custom metadata for a file, such as tags, IDs from other data stores, information shared between workflow applications, and so on.

To add properties visible to all apps, use the properties field of files resource."

In the Google API Files Page, it lists it as
"properties": {
(key): string}
I've tried a number of different ways to pass a value, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have an example of adding a custom property while creating a folder?

Here is one example I've tried that does not work:

```
GDriveTarget <- "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/'etc'"

drID <- drive_get(GDriveTarget, verbose = TRUE)

gProps <-list2(properties = c("Region","Far Northeast"))
curFolder <- drive_mkdir(name="School Folders", 
                        path=GDriveTarget,
                        gProps)
```

this results in:
Error: These parameters are unknown:

Backtrace:

1. googledrive::drive_mkdir(...)
2. googledrive::drive_create(...)
3. googledrive::request_generate(...)
4. gargle::request_develop(endpoint = ept, params = params)
5. gargle:::check_params(params, endpoint$parameters)
6. gargle:::stop_bad_params(unknown, reason = "unknown")

Removing "gProps" creates the desired folder, so I have the proper rights. I'm just unsure how to pass the parameters Google is expecting. When I use the "try this API" tool on Google Developer, what it is expecting is:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "Region": "Far Northeast"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include example of code that you tried?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel, I've updated the question with examples. Admittedly, I've not used list2() before, so that is probably where the issue is, particularly since the Google API is expecting property name/value pairs in a specific way.